# How to ignore all inputs after first character with scanf in loop?

Tags: c, loops, scanf

I'm asking user to input character, but the problem is that if user inputs multiple characters, the loop will be executed for all characters.

```
    do
    {
        printf("For input type 'u', for output type 'p': ");
        scanf("%c", &c); 
    } while ((c != 'u') && (c != 'p'));
```

So if user for example types `'aaaa'`, loop will be executed 5 times with repeated `printf` text. I tried `getchar();` after `scanf`, using conversion string `" %c"`, `"%c%*c` but nothing worked. Is there a way to execute loop for only first character?

Comment: [Read the whole line](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), get the first character, and ignore the rest?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to print the statement only one time in case the character is other than u/p. if it is yes, you can move the print statement *above the do loop* or use the condition statement by checking c value is set or not. It will print the statement only once.
My syntax may be incorrect, check the c programming guide.

```
1. 
    printf("");
       do{
         }while

2.     do{
               if(c != '\0')
               {
                printf("For input type 'u', for output type 'p':");
               }
            scanf('%c',&c);
           } while ((c != 'u') && (c != 'p'));
```